# Como detectar um bot

Tags: php, javascript

Estou ajudando um amigo a desenvolver um sistema de visitas, como o [Rede Grana](http://www.redegrana.com.br/) ex: Grana Social.
Acontece que faremos pagamentos por visitas reais na página, e como sabemos que existem pessoas mal intencionadas e que tentarão burlar o sistema para tirar vantagem e ganhar visualizações, como por exemplo usar um usuário fictício, um *bot* ([HitLeap](https://hitleap.com/)).

Preciso saber diferenciar uma visualização real de uma visualização por *bot*. Já procurei uma solução com o `HTTP_USER_AGENt` mas não conseguir nada, também comparei ele com visualizações reais e não encontrei nada que possa usar.

Qual seria a melhor solução para se proteger deste tipo de caso, algo como o YouTube já consegue realizar, distinguir os acessos reais dos não reai.

Desde já agradeço...

P.S.: Sei como detectar os indexadores comuns! Então não me mostre artigos que falem do *googlebot.*

Comment: como disse, Daniel, você pode verificar se é um robô através do [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

Comment: É algo desagradável para o usuário isto. Pois o proposito não interagir com a página, somente visualiza-la.

Comment: Veja [se isso](http://www.cult-f.net/detect-crawlers-with-php/) te ajuda.

Comment: Como você sabe que eu não sou um bot comentando aqui pra você no SOPT?

Comment: @IvanFerrer não era isso...

Comment: E @LuizVieira acho que um bot não iria me perguntar isso.

Comment: Um bot suficientemente bem feito poderia perguntar isso. Na verdade tem outros indicativos de que eu não sou um bot que são melhores do que a minha mensagem anterior ou mesmo essa. Vc pode olhar, por exemplo, o meu histórico de participação no site. O meu ponto com essa brincadeira (desculpe por ela, aliás, era só uma brincadeira) é que sem analisar algum histórico de interação vai ser difícil detectar algo. A não ser que você faça como as respostas que você tem já sugerem, e ignore origens sabidamente de bots. São soluções muito boas, mas não necessarimaente infalíveis. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acho que a única maneira eficaz é usando [Captcha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA), outras maneiras são fáceis de burlar.

Existem boas maneiras de estimar o número de visitantes, um exemplo é o [*view count* do SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated), mas mesmo esse método pode ser burlado com bots distribuídos ou usando [Proxy](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy).

Comment: Essa resposta era inicialmente um comentário, mas, se não tiver nada melhor, acho que ela já é boa para te indicar um caminho pra pesquisar mais.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de fazer isso, é criando regras no `.htaccess`, que impeçam alguns agentes conhecidos que são robôs, daí você teria que ter uma lista completa ou buscar uma lista complexa destes agentes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Twitterbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Baiduspider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MetaURI [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mediawords [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} FlipboardProxy [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/sem_crawler.htm
RewriteRule .* http://seusite.com.br/sem_crawler.htm [L]
```

Outra maneira é fazendo uso do PHP:

```
<?php 
class CrawlerDetect
{
   //lista de robôs
  private $agentsInvalids = array(
    'Google'=>'Google',
    'MSN' => 'msnbot',
    'Rambler'=>'Rambler',
    'Yahoo'=> 'Yahoo',
    'AbachoBOT'=> 'AbachoBOT',
    'accoona'=> 'Accoona',
    'AcoiRobot'=> 'AcoiRobot',
    'ASPSeek'=> 'ASPSeek',
    'CrocCrawler'=> 'CrocCrawler',
    'Dumbot'=> 'Dumbot',
    'FAST-WebCrawler'=> 'FAST-WebCrawler',
    'GeonaBot'=> 'GeonaBot',
    'Gigabot'=> 'Gigabot',
    'Lycos spider'=> 'Lycos',
    'MSRBOT'=> 'MSRBOT',
    'Altavista robot'=> 'Scooter',
    'AltaVista robot'=> 'Altavista',
    'ID-Search Bot'=> 'IDBot',
    'eStyle Bot'=> 'eStyle',
    'Scrubby robot'=> 'Scrubby',
    ...
    );
//lista de navegadores válidos
private $agentsValids = array(
    'Mozilla' => 'Mozilla',
    'Chrome'  => 'Chrome',
    'Safari'  => 'Safari',
    'Opera'   => 'Opera',
     ...
);


public function __construct($USER_AGENT)
{
    $invalids =  implode('|',$this->agentsInvalids);
    $valids =  implode('|',$this->agentsValids);
    /* aqui você escolhe como prefere,
    acredito que basta testar uma única lista */
    if (strpos($invalids, $USER_AGENT) !== false ||
        strpos($valids, $USER_AGENT) === false) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}

//verifica o navegador

$crawler = new CrawlerDetect($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

//se for robô ele verifica
if ($crawler) {
  echo "acesso inválido!";
} else {
  echo "acesso válido!"; 
}
```

[**Neste site**](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) tem uma lista completa ou próxima disso, que mostra uma listas completa de brownsers e Crawlers.

Comment: Meu problema é com outros tipos de bots. Google, Yahoo, Facebook tem um HTTP_USER_AGENT unico, ja os usando com o HitLeap o HTTP_USER_AGENT é como de um usuario comum.
Google=> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Usuario comum e usuarios com HitLeap => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; SM-G530BT Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/77.0.0.20.66;]

É muito facil identificar um bot de um indexador, agora esses criados pelos proprios usuarios ja não sei como.

Comment: Então por que você não indexa somente os permitidos, assim barra todos os outros. Veja que publiquei o endereço do site que tem navegadores comuns.

Comment: Uma maneira de você evitar BOTS é obtendo informações pessoais, não existem maneiras melhores que esta. Outra forma é você obter um raciocínio lógico do usuário, ou seja, criar algo que só um usuário poderia acessar.